# Safari Search Field Cancel Button Callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, webkit

I have a table with some fields and I do a "live search" to find the rows…

My code for this is this:

```
 $("#searchforpage").keyup(function(pd) {
      pd.preventDefault();
      $("table tbody tr").hide();
  $("table tbody").find("tr:contains('"+$("#searchforpage").val().toLowerCase()+"')").show();
 });
```

This works and is not the real problem, but my input field is a type="search" so that safari has the magnifying glass and the search history and the x in the right corner.

And the x is the problem if clicked nothing happens because the hole code responds to keyup.

so i would want to do something like that to show all rows again:

```
$("#searchforpage::-webkit-search-cancel-button").click(function() {
  $("table tbody tr").show();
});
```

How do I get a callback form the cancel button to show all rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok my workaround for this is now that i now use every click in the search field…
my thought is that if you click in the field again you probably want to search for something completely different:

```
$("#searchforpage").click(function() {
   $(this).val("");
   $("table tbody tr").show();
});
```

But if someone has a correct solution for this i would like to know it.